# comparison of symbols to its ascii values

Tags: java, android, xml

While designing chess in android i used ascii values for symbols. When button with pawn is clicked i am getting its symbol.Now i want to compare this symbol with its value.

```
Button myButton = (Button) v
src=myButton.getText().toString();
if(src.equals("&#9823;"))
{
  //code..
}
```

I am clicking on black pawn. So src containing the symbol of black pawn. Black pawn ascii value is (♟).But while executing above code the condition is showing false.
How to compare symbols to its ascii values.

Comment: Have you get the src in setonclick listener.?

Comment: i got src in onClick listener

Comment: Have you tried `src.equals("♟")`

Comment: i tried, its given in the question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
Button myButton = (Button) v
src=myButton.getText().toString();
if(src.equals("\u265f"))
{
  //code..
}
```

You can look up the Unicode number [here](http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/?start=9823&end=9824&cols=1&search=&show_uni_int=on&show_uni_hex=on&show_html_ent=on&show_raw_hex=on&show_raw_bin=on) and use that.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String t = "♟";     
    System.out.println(t.equals("\u265f")); //true
}
```